# how to apply logback-spring.xml file to multiple java packages/folders?

Tags: spring, logback, properties-file, spring-logback

Currently I have 12 same logback-spring.xml files in 12 folders. I would like to replace them with one and specify it in f.e. data.properties file, which applies to all of my folders..
I tried to specify it like this (in data.properties) file:

```
logging.config.import = classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

But the output gives me an error:

***Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback-spring.xml***

Could you help me with other approaches, please?